# Can't access several websites on Wired connection

Tags: networking, ethernet, wired

I can't access several websites on my Laptop using a wired connection. I am using GTPL(ISP) broadband. One of which is `quora.com`. When I try to access quora, I get following message:

```
This site can’t be reached

www.quora.com took too long to respond.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

I am using Dell Inspiron 3542 with Ubuntu 16.04 & no antivirus.

Comment: What happens if you tracert/pathping to www.quora.com? Can you reach it?

Comment: What happens if you set your interface MTU down to 1300?

Comment: @DavidPostill, it shows "This site can’t be reached" error. But If I use a VPN or mobile hotpsot then it works fine.

Comment: @Spiff I tried setting MTU to 1300 but still it doesn't work.